# Account management system

Tags: magento2, login, customer-account

I would like the user to be able to sign up for an account/login from a link on the home page. But they also need to be able to create an account/login during the shopping cart checkout process.

I assume that I won't need to go to the Magento Marketplace to find what I need. It is intuitive that the account system is included in the Magento base install. Am I correct?

How do I integrate the account system on both of those two pages?

Comment: is your login link in header? it will always be there. see default theme and check your theme

Comment: We are using a custom theme. The address for the login page isn't in the header. One of our developers set up the home page, and it says, "Account". And he just used a URL for that link "http://localhost:8000/create-an-account/". Do we need to create login/signup pages in the pages section of the admin panel ourselves, because we are using a custom template? Is there a resource online that describes what blocks of code to put into the pages that allow for login/sign up?

Comment: Nice! I compared my theme with the default theme and found the correct links. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a custom theme, the links for the account system may not be correct. Check out this demo and use the links with your Magento install.

Demo:
http://magento2-demo.nexcess.net